# Installing windows xp on my external drive how can I do it

Tags: windows-xp

My laptop with a windows xp was corrupted .My brother formatted it.Now I am stuck.
The cd rom does not work on the laptop and even though I have the disk i cannot do it.

I have a desktop computer witn Windows 7 and I thought If

- I remove the hard disk from the laptop
- put in an enclosure
- connect the enclose to the desktop
- insert windows xp on the windows 7 desktop
- find a way to install windows xp on my enclosure

Nearly forgot!!
I now get on the laptop "BootManager" is missing TOO

however it's not that simple

Given my situation  what it is the best way to install windows xp on my laptop?
ANy walkthrough instructions?

thanks a lot

Comment: If you haven't done anything to the laptop HDD  you could probably use testdisk to recover the original install - this will ONLY WORK if you have not done anything else to the hard drive.
In addition, i'd ask, what error prevents an xp install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your laptop supports booting from USB memory devices then the simplest method would be to use a cheap USB memory stick (1GB or more) to install XP direct on the laptop.

There is a good walkthrough here: http://liliputing.com/2008/04/install-windows-xp-on-mini-note-usb.html

Answer (score -1):

If the external enclosure is connected via USB then you cannot install Windows XP on it.